# Azure Redis Cache: super slow List*Pop/Push operations

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm working with StackExchange.Redis library, with ListLeftPush() and ListRightPop(). They are super slow. The same code on the standalone Redis is thousand times faster.

Maybe the Azure Redis Cache is suboptimal for these operations?

Somebody could help with it? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you think the issue is with StackExchange.Redis or Azure Redis Cache?  Have you tried using StackExchange.Redis with a standalone Redis server?  How about using Azure Redis Cache with a different client like redis-cli.exe?

Also, can you post code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: It would be useful to know which version of StackExchange.Redis that you are using.

Comment: Have you checked the Azure portal where you can monitor your Redis cache? Maybe something abnormal shows up there?